# Javascript if condition for RoR

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, if-statement

I am trying to use Javascript in my RoR4 app.

The problem I have is that when there are 2 if-conditions, the second one always get executed even it shouldn't be.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if (document.body.contains('individual'))
{
    alert('first');    
} else if (document.body.contains('main'))
  {
    <% if current_user.activated%>
        alert('not activated');
    <% else %>
        alert('activated');
    <% end %>
  }
})
```

**Edit***
Even without the ruby if, the below code still doesn't work. The second statement is still loaded when the div is not existing and thus causing error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if (document.getElementById('individual'))
{
    $("#individual").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'post', locals: { items: @posts} ) %>");        
}
else 
{
    $("#user").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'history', locals: { items: @history} ) %>");
  }
})
```

Comment: I have tried to use getElementById instead of contains as well, still no luck

Comment: Would this be caused by server side execution, ie the ruby if, got executed first, and then the client side script, ie javascript if, got executed later and that cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

if (expression 1){
   Statement(s) to be executed if expression 1 is true
}

else if (expression 2){
   Statement(s) to be executed if expression 2 is true
}

else if (expression 3){
   Statement(s) to be executed if expression 3 is true
}

else{
   Statement(s) to be executed if no expression is true
}

Comment: I have tried this, and without the escape_javascript bit, it's fine. But when I include escape_javascript into if clause, then the whole loop doesn't work